# is the networkserver connectionId like an list in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-networking

Hi I have been thinking about this question for a bit now and can't seem to get an answer.
My question is. Is the networkServer connectionId like an list in unity c#?

I'm thinking like this.
lets say we have two players connected to the server.

```
player_1 = connectionId 0   
player_2 = connectionId 1
```

what would happen if let's say player_1 disconnects. would that make player_2 move down to the first row and get the connectionId of player_1?

```
player_1 = disconnected(no connectionId then)  
player_2 = connectionId 0
```

or would he stay at the same connectionId? and if so what would happen if a third player connects? would he be set in front of the line and take player_1's old connectionId?

```
player_3 = connectionId 0  
player_2 = connectionId 1
```

or would he be set to the back of the line? and get a new connectionId

```
player_1 = disconnected(no connectionId then)  
player_2 = connectionId 1  
player_3 = connectionId 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what would happen if let's say player_1 disconnects. would that make
>   player_2 move down to the first row and get the connectionId of
>   player_1?

**No**.

> or would he stay at the same connectionId? and if so what would happen
>   if a third player connects? would he be set in front of the line and
>   take player_1's old connectionId?

Each connection get a **unique** ID.

Read the [Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.NetworkConnection-connectionId.html) of an API whenever you are confused.

Quote from the Doc:

> Unique identifier for this connection that is assigned by the
>   transport layer.
>
> On a server, this Id is unique for every connection on the server. On
>   a client this Id is local to the client, it is not the same as the Id
>   on the server for this connection.

So, the ID remains the-same when **other** NetworkConnection are connected or disconnected.

The only time the value of [`NetworkConnection.connectionId`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.NetworkConnection-connectionId.html) may change is when the device/client disconnects and connects again. In this case, it is giving another id when it reconnects again but this should not affect devices/clients that are still connected. Their IDs should still remain the-same.

Comment: "The only time the value of NetworkConnection.connectionId may   
change is when the device/client disconnects and connects again.   
In this case, it is giving another id when it reconnects again"

But then what happends to the old connectionId? that he previously owned? Is it given to another player? or will it never get used?

Comment: Not sure about that one. I tried to do a quick test but there is a bug with `NetworkConnection.connectionId` on my side. It returns 0 all the time. I suggest you experiment and see if disconnected and connected items get assigned new ID or use old ID.